# Google Maps in Grayscale

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Is there any way to display a Google Map (embedded via the Javascript API) in grayscale without losing any other functionality?

Comment: I doubt it. It might be possible in IE by overlaying the map with a DIV that uses one of the DirectX `filter` CSS properties to make anything underneath it grayscale, but it would also overlay the controls. Interested to see whether anything comes up

Comment: Related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/5964/how-to-apply-custom-google-map-style-in-openlayers

Answer (score 117, accepted):

Yes, in V3 of the api they have introduced [`StyledMaps`](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes.html#StyledMaps).

They've even [provided a tool](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html) for you to generate the code for the styles you like. Slide the "Saturation" all the way down and you've got grayscale going on!

The following example displays a grayscale map of Brooklyn:

```
var map;
var brooklyn = new google.maps.LatLng(40.6743890, -73.9455);

var stylez = [
    {
      featureType: "all",
      elementType: "all",
      stylers: [
        { saturation: -100 } // <-- THIS
      ]
    }
];

var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 11,
    center: brooklyn,
    mapTypeControlOptions: {
         mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, 'tehgrayz']
    }
};

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

var mapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(stylez, { name:"Grayscale" });    
map.mapTypes.set('tehgrayz', mapType);
map.setMapTypeId('tehgrayz');
```

Comment: How to return as it was before the changes ?

Answer (score 45):

There's a little shorter way (comparing to @Roatin Marth's [best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003578/google-maps-in-grayscale#4003664)) to make your Google map grayscale with [Google Maps JavaScript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) by directly including styles you generated with [Google Maps API Styled Map Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html) into `google.maps.MapOptions` object:

```
var container = document.getElementById('map_canvas');
var mapOptions = {
  zoom: 11,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(40.6743890, -73.9455),
  styles: [{
    stylers: [{
      saturation: -100
    }]
  }]
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(container, mapOptions);
```

You get the array set under `styles` property in `mapOptions` variable by clicking onto "Show JSON" button inside Map Style panel when finishing your styles customisation using [Google Maps API Styled Map Wizard](http://gmaps-samples-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/styledmaps/wizard/index.html).

[image: JSON output demonstrating styles array to set into mapOptions]

Comment: Much better solution!

Comment: Much simpler and better solution imo. Should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 16):

Just use [CSS3 grayscale()](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/FXTF/raw-file/tip/filters/index.html) filter effect for the Google maps iframe element! It works because the js code prints images.

```
iframe { 
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
  -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: grayscale(100%);
  filter: url(grayscale.svg); /* Firefox 4+ */
  filter: gray; /* IE 6-9 */
}
```

Try also to target **only the background images** by applying this to the very first div element under the `div.gm-style` (or any other wrapper). I don't know if Google changes the dom structure often but at the moment speaking (25 Nov 2014) this works fine.

```
iframe .gm-style > div:first-child {
  // Same code here
}
```

Comment: ..beware.. colored map marker will be displayed in grayscale too.

Comment: Finally the one I've been looking for! I like this one as it turns everything into grayscale. The problem with the js solution is that you lose some of the defaults in the map embed.

Comment: This is brilliant. - I had a problem with grayscale.svg, ommited that line and it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Use the CSS filter property to convert the google map to black and white. 100% is completely black and white

```
selector {
  -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); /* Safari 6.0 - 9.0 */
  filter: grayscale(100%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IE has the `filter: gray` directive.

It renders any HTML element in grayscale. JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cTduB/2/).

You *may* be able to apply this to the map's parent DIV. It *may* turn the map it contains in to a grayscale represtenation. I can't say whether this will work without side effects - you'd have to try. But it's well possible.

IE only, though, but supported since Version 4.

[Grayscale Filter docs at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533003%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Other than that, I think there is a Flash API for Maps, isn't there? It might be easier to achieve there.

Comment: Having the map in grayscale for IE only wouldn't be particularly helpful seeing as the rest of the application is being coded using HTML5 and Canvas - thanks for the answer though!

Comment: @DliKS yeah. I don't think there is a cross-browser way to do this, the `filter` stuff never caught on in other browsers. Sadly! ... It may be possible in Flash, I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this:

http://snazzymaps.com/style/15/subtle-grayscale

Works like a charm :)

Answer (score -2):

Yes, there is a third party API for Google maps that provides gray-scale (snazzymaps).

Its very simple. You can use this website to get the different color scheme for google maps.

http://snazzymaps.com

Answer (score -14):

Apart from writing the good people at Google and asking them to create grey-scale versions of all of their image tiles and an optional API parameter, no.